# Can someone give me an example on how I can call $resource directly?

Tags: angularjs

In my code I have:

```
    var EntityResource = $resource('/api/:entityType', {}, {
        postEntity: { url: '/api/:entityType/', method: 'POST' },
        getEntity: { url: '/api/:entityType/:entityId', method: 'GET' },
        putEntity:     { url: '/api/:entityType/:entityId', method: 'PUT' },
        deleteEntity: { url: '/api/:entityType/:entityId', method: "DELETE" },
        getEntities: { url: '/api/:entityType/:action/:id', method: 'GET', isArray: true },
    });
```

Then I am using the following to get data:

```
    getProjects: function (
            entityType,
            deptId) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            EntityResource.getEntities({
                action: "GetProjects",
                entityType: entityType,
                deptId: deptId
            },
               function (resp) {
                   deferred.resolve(resp);
               }
            );
            return deferred.promise;
        },
```

and the following to call getProjects:

```
            entityService.getProjects(
                'Project',
                $scope.option.selectedDept)
            .then(function (result) {
                $scope.grid.data = result;
            }, function (result) {
                $scope.grid.data = null;
            });
```

I think the intermediate function getProjects is not needed and I would like to directly use $resource.

Can someone give me some advice on how I could do this? I looked at the AngularJS documentation for $resource and it's not very clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

$resource calls by default return empty arrays and then fill them up when the response is received. As mentioned in [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method
>   immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on
>   isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing
>   reference is populated with the actual data.

There are default 5 methods already defined on resource, `get,save,query,remove,delete`. You can directly call these rather than defining your own as you have done like `postEntity`, but the url template remains the same.

So once you define resource like this

```
var entityResource = $resource('/api/:entityType');
```

you can make calls like

```
var entity=entityResource.get({entityType:1},function(data) {
    //The entity would be filled now
});
```

See the `User` example in documentation

If you want to return promise then you have to wrap the calls into your your service calls like you did for getProjects.

**Update**: Based on your comment, the definition could be

```
var entityResource = $resource('/api/:entityType/:action/:id')
```

Now if you do

```
entityResource.get({},function(){})  // The query is to /api
entityResource.get({entityType:'et'},function(){})  // The query is to /api/et
entityResource.get({entityType:'et',:action:'a'},function(){})  // The query is to /api/et/a
entityResource.get({entityType:'et',:action:'a',id:1},function(){})  // The query is to /api/et/a/1
```

Hope it helps.

$resource does expose $promise but it is on return values and subsequent calls.

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed reply. If you don't mind can you show me how you would code a call to get the project data that I need for my application? I understand I would need to do as you say with "var entityResource" but how would I need to handle the action, entityType and deptId parameters?

Comment: @Chndermani - Thanks for your reply. I see you created examples but how could I for example create a get if the URL was The query is to /api/et/action?deptId=25&abc=3  This is my big problem. I am not sure how to add these additional params. When I look at the AngularJS documentation it seems I can't see any mention of where a user could pass many parameters.

Comment: the template should be `api/:entityType/action/`. Thats it. Now whatever parameters you pass in the invocation, it would first try to bind it to token in the url, else all extra become part of querystring.

Comment: But can you show me how to pass parameters in the invocation? Sorry but it's not so clear for me as the documentation does not seem to give an example. Just a one line example would really help me. Thank you.

Comment: This is also mentioned in documentation "Each key value in the parameter object is first bound to url template if present and then any excess keys are appended to the url search query after the ?."

Comment: I already did. The `get` methods that I have shown, the first parameter is the one i am talking about.

Comment: oh okay so do you mean I can code it like this: var entityResource = $resource('/api/Product/GetData')
entityResource.get({},function(){deptId=22, abc= 33}) and then the deptId and abc will be query parameters ?

Comment: No, entityResource.get({deptId=22,abc=33},function{//this is a callabck!})